# Core service Generic exception issue

Tags: 2011, core-service

I have a project in ASP.NET WebAPI that uses Core Service to CRUD components, when I try to create a component I have a FaultException'1 with this message :

> {   "$id": "1",   "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Could not find endpoint element with name
>   'TridionCoreService' and contract
>   'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client
>   element.",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault,
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b]]",   "StackTrace": "
>   Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService.Save(IdentifiableObjectData
>   deltaData, ReadOptions readBackOptions)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient.Save(IdentifiableObjectData
>   deltaData, ReadOptions readBackOptions)    at
>   *.Web.Tridion.UI.Logic.TridionCoreServiceManager.CreatePageSettings(ConfigurationComponent
>   args) in C:\*\New
>   folder\Sites\Dev\Tridion\*.Web.Tridion.UI\Logic\TridionCoreServiceManager.cs:line
>   116    at
>   *.Web.Tridion.UI.Logic.TridionCoreServiceManager.CreateConfigurationComponent(ConfigurationComponent
>   args) in C:\*\New
>   folder\Sites\Dev\Tridion\*.Web.Tridion.UI\Logic\TridionCoreServiceManager.cs:line
>   97    at
>   *.Web.Tridion.UI.Controllers.TridionController.Create(ConfigurationComponent
>   component) in C:\*\New
>   folder\Sites\Dev\Tridion\*.Web.Tridion.UI\Controllers\TridionController.cs:line
>   42    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c_*DisplayClassf.b*_9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
>
> }

I'm really surprised because I can read schemas :

```
using (var tridion = new CoreServiceAgent())
{
    componentToCreate = tridion.Client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component,
                                                      ConfigurationContainerId) as ComponentData;
    componentToCreate.Title = itemNumber.ToString();

    schemaFields = tridion.Client.ReadSchemaFields("tcm:174-277976-8", true,
                                                    new ReadOptions());

    Fields fields = new Fields(schemaFields, schemaFields.Fields, 
                               componentToCreate.Content, "Configuration");
    fields["Slogan"].AddValue(args.Slogan);
    componentToCreate.Content = fields.OuterXml;
    tridion.Client.Create(componentToCreate, new ReadOptions());
}
```

The exception is thrown when `Create()` is called.

The configuration is written is web.config, I can read components but I can't save/create/update.

I suppose that's a generic exception (if I can read, I can create) but I don't get why and how to solve it, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the `CoreServiceAgent` class, it looks like as a Wrapper or a Facade to the `CoreServiceClient` class, please check how the `CoreServiceClient` class is instantiated and check the endpoint that is being used (basicHttp, wsHttp, netTcp, ...).

Check if the WCF client configuration is located in your application Web.config file. In case you don't have the WCF client configuration in the Web.config file, it is also possible to [configure an endpoint by code](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html#!/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html).

Comment: Yes, Core Service Agent is a Facade to CoreServiceClient.

Answer (score 0):

Client configuration seems to be missing under service model. Refer below sample configuration

### Example:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="TridionCoreService" address="XXXXX" binding="YYYYYY" 
                contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService"/>
    </client> 
</system.serviceModel>
```